# how to convert subscr_date and subscr_effective to mysql date

Tags: mysql, datetime, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

Auto-answering my own question since the objective is to help you guys out with IPN, which is hardcore enough to save yourself this step...

Reminder: it is about converting the following fields of Paypal IPN:

- `$_POST['subscr_date']`
- `$_POST['subscr_effective']`

To a mysql `DATE` value.

Hope it helps!
Cheers,
S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you ever wondered how to convert these dates to mysql, here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION  IF EXISTS ppdate_to_mysqldate$$

CREATE FUNCTION ppdate_to_mysqldate(I_PP_EFFECTIVE_DATE VARCHAR(32)) RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE dteStart DATE;

    /*
        I_PP_EFFECTIVE_DATE:    
        . from doc:
            Date when the subscription modification will be effective.
            Time/Date stamp generated by PayPal, in the following format: HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST
        . from real example: 
            03:00:00 Mar 11, 2013 PDT
            06:56:24 Feb 11, 2013 PST
    */

    IF INSTR(I_PP_EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'PDT') > 0 THEN
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE(I_PP_EFFECTIVE_DATE, '%H:%i:%s %b %e, %Y PDT') INTO dteStart FROM DUAL;
    ELSE 
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE(I_PP_EFFECTIVE_DATE, '%H:%i:%s %b %e, %Y PST') INTO dteStart FROM DUAL;
    END IF;

    RETURN dteStart;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('03:00:00 Mar 11, 2013 PDT'));` maybe?

Comment: Yes but which sdk do you use for the ipn?

Comment: I_PP_EFFECTIVE_DATE is the value extracted directly from $_POST['subscr_date'] or $_POST['subscr_effective']

Comment: And I assume you store them then to mysql. So strtotime gets any valid datetime string (human read) and converts it to unixtime, why do a stored procedure for something built-in?

Comment: because i'm not manipulating dates in php, only in mysql, and my whole framework is under stored procedures.

Comment: Even though Sebas needed a MySQL solution, @Panagiotis is the smartest and simplest option and works for me when I came searching for an answer to the same problem. Especially as I'm using PHP in an MVC framework, to run the queries to store my data in MySQL. Tah!

Answer (score 1):

Java users just need to use a `SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss MMM dd, yyyy z")`.

Note that the documentation of this format in the IPN Guide ("HH:MM:SS DD Mmm YY, YYYY PST") is incorrect, as you can tell by the dual year fields.

And note also, as I just established today, that what the sandbox Test IPN tool sends is yet a third format.

Answer (score 0):

As https://stackoverflow.com/users/670078/panagiotis pointed out, if you are using PHP, the simplest answer is to use strtotime conversion.

Here's a more complete copy/paste PHP solution:

```
$subscr_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['subscr_date']));
$subscr_effective = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST['subscr_effective']));
```

Using a function might be better for some (though it is more code, I'm often accused of doing things 'simple' instead of 'best practice'.... ;)

```
function changePaypalDateToMySQL($paypalDate){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($paypalDate));
}

$subscr_date = changePaypalDateToMySQL($_POST['subscr_date']);
$subscr_effective = changePaypalDateToMySQL($_POST['subscr_effective']);
```

As an additional note, PayPal supports webhooks https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/rest-webhooks/ which are typically 'better' than IPN https://www.paypal-engineering.com/2014/10/07/webhooks-for-rest-apis-launched/ and are recommended.